# Can I upload the files from console application to google drive in specific folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a requirement. Insert the file from console application to `google drive` through code.

I read some articles, but I didn't understand. please help me...

Comment: with code. Please write some

Comment: you need to write some code.

Answer (score 1):

Google dev website has what you are looking for. Also, please at least try some code before asking questions here so we can help fixing it.

```
class Program
{
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json
    static string[] Scopes = {  DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

        // Define parameters of request.
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 10;
        listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

        // List files.
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
            .Files;
        Console.WriteLine("Files:");
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
        }
        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

For further, check the following link.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet